# Echo in the Azure Pipelines's YAML file prints different things

Tags: bash, azure, yaml, echo, azure-pipelines

I have this code inside my YAML file for an Azure pipeline:

```
steps:
- bash: |
    echo $(date +%Y)
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildName]$(date +%Y)_$(date +%m)_$(Build.BuildNumber)_v3.7"
    echo $BUILDNAME
```

The first `echo` correctly prints `2020`, but the third print `$(date +%Y)_$(date +%m)_4728573844_v3.7`. As you can see, here the year and month are not translated into values. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected action which caused by [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts) of `variable`.

> To set a variable from a script, you use the task.setvariable logging
>   command. This doesn't update the environment variables, but it does
>   make the new variable available to downstream steps within the same
>   job.

The nutshell is when you use `task.setvariable` command to new one variable in **Bash** task, the variable you created will not available in current Bash task. It only available in next steps.

So, here, when you add another **Bash** task and `echo` this variable you created `buildName`. You will see it is created successfully:

```
steps:
- bash: |
    echo $(date +%Y)
    echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildName]$(date +%Y)_$(date +%m)_$(Build.BuildNumber)_v3.7'

- bash: |
    echo $(buildName)
```

[image]